# How do I use the Excel Union function through Win32::OLE? 

Tags: perl, excel, perl-module, win32ole, activeperl

I am using Win32::OLE to create charts from a excel datasheet in MSExcel 2010.
The data are not in consecutive columns and I have a ds having the range of each data.
I am trying to union all these data ranges to a single range object like :

```
my $range = $self->{'workbook'}->Application->Union( $range, $r );
```

It works fine, till "$BS$1:$BS$168". The next data is in the range "$BW$1:$BW$168". This range is not getting united with the previous range and I am left with only 18 collected data instead of 46.

What may be the reason and workaround?
Is there any limit, to the number of series you can collect?

Answer (score 0):

According [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/7546f763-26c3-4b37-a2bd-f41254a6187f/) there is a limit 255 for address length, including all punctuation.  Your example range is 13 characters plus one for separator, giving you around 18 items maximum.

Conclusion is to limit number of items or their length. Could you merge multiple columns together (`$BS$1:$BW$168`), or leave `$`s out for instance?